# How can I take a large piece of text in one cell and insert carriage returns to break it up into multiple cells?

Tags: excel, sqlite, csv, carriage-return

So I am working on prepping my data for insertion into a sqlite db. Historically, I have put it into excel, and the data in different cells has equated to different rows in my db table (through csv importation).

So now I have a huge bit of text that I have pulled from a webpage which is just in one cell, but I need to break the text up into different cells. How can I insert a carriage return? Or is there a way I can send the data into excel with a symbol that will automatically put it into separate cells? Or could I possibly make my own custom csv file? Aside from cutting the text I want to move, is there a more efficient way?

There are numbers that are in the text that are unique and increasing that I could use to insert something, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A 10 step solution…

1. Select the cell with the huge text:
   [image: step01]
2. Insert your delimiter character (e.g. I chose '#') anywhere you wish:
   [image: step02]
3. Replace hard returns by your delimiter character:
   [image: step03]
   You can also choose to do the latter with a formula:
   `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"` <— insert ALT+ENTER here for a hard return between the quotes
   `","#")`
   This way you will not accidentally skip any hard returns (the conversion wizard chokes on them).
4. Start the Text to Columns conversion wizard for the selected cell:
   [image: step04]
5. Choose delimited:
   [image: step05]
6. Choose delimiter:
   [image: step06]
7. Copy the resulting range of cells in order to transpose them:
   [image: step07]
8. Choose Paste Special on the starting cell for pasting the transposed range:
   [image: step08]
9. Select Transpose…
   [image: step09]
10. DONE!
    [image: step10]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of working in Excel, you can also manipulate the CSV file. Just respect the CSV basics and you should be able to (experiment a little and then) get the job done:

*A CSV file holds Comma-Separated Values, in a delimited data format that has fields/columns separated by the comma character and records/rows terminated by newlines.

Fields that contain a special character (comma, newline, or double quote), must be enclosed in double quotes, after doubling any existing double quotes (to escape those).*

So if you take a look a the huge cell in CSV format (just use any plain text editor), it probably spans several lines and is enclosed in double quotes, like this?
[image: before]
You can split up that one quoted multiline text into e.g. several quote single lines of text, such as shown below:
[image: after]